# Sylow $p$-subgroups of Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

It just my curious, but I couldn’t find any related concept:

Condition)

> Let $G$ be a finite Galois group, and the number of each Sylow $p_{i}$-subgroup of $G$ is one, where $p_{i}$ is a prime factor of $|G|$.

Question)

Under the above condition, is it true $G$ is cyclic?

Give some advice or related notion! Thank you!

Comment: All Sylow subgroups being normal is well known to be equivalent to the group $G$ being nilpotent. There are non-cyclic nilpotent groups. In fact every $p$-group is nilpotent ...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually, I was solving the following problems:

Let $K$ be a Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=540$, let $G:=G(K/\mathbb{Q})$ be the Galois group so that the number of each Sylow subgroup of $G$ is one.

I don't know who made it, the solution of the above problem claims that $G$ is cyclic without any proof.

I don't understand how to guarantee $G$ is cyclic.

Since $G\cong P_{2}\times P_{3}\times P_{5}$, where each $P_{i}$ is a Sylow $i$-subgroup of $G$, I think there is no guarantee that $G$ is cyclic.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: $540=2^2\cdot3^3\cdot5$. There are non-cyclic groups of orders $2^2$ and $3^3$, so you cannot conclude that $G$ would be cyclic based on that piece of data alone. Yes, something is missing from that exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every finite group is a Galois group of some finite extension $L/K$
of fields.

If a finite group has a unique Sylow subgroup for each prime, then all
one can conclude is that it is nilpotent, that is a direct
product of $p$-groups. It need not be cyclic, or indeed Abelian.